# Shiny conditional panel

Tags: r, shiny

In my app I want the user to choose a folder, and the to choose a file from that folder.

I thought to use `conditionalPanel()` so the user will see only the first button until he pick's the folder. I wrote this code but I get this error message, 'object 'input' is not found', what would be the right way to do this? And is it a problem to put a conditional panel in an absolute panel?

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(""),
  fluidRow(
    # select input for selecting a folder
    column(2, absolutePanel(fixed = TRUE, width = '180px',
                      selectInput("pick_folder", label = '', selected='choose_a_folder',
                              choices = setNames(as.list(c('choose_a_folder', basename(setdiff(list.dirs(recursive = FALSE),'.')))), 
                                                 c('choose_a_folder', basename(setdiff(list.dirs(recursive = FALSE),'.'))))))),
    # select input for selecting a file absolutePanel then conditionalPanel
    column(2, absolutePanel(fixed = TRUE, width = '180px', 
                      conditionalPanel(condition="input.pick_folder==choose_a_folder",
                                 selectInput('pick_file', label = '', selected = 'choose_a_file',
                                           choices = setNames(as.list(c('choose_a_file', basename(setdiff(list.files(path=input$pick_folder ,recursive = FALSE),'.')))), 
                                                              c('choose a file', basename(setdiff(list.files(path=input$pick_folder ,recursive = FALSE),'.')))))))),
  ),
  fluidRow(
    #plot
    plotOutput('my_plot')

    )))

  # server
  server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$my_plot <- renderPlot({
      dat <- read.table(file=paste(input$pick_folder, input$pick_file, sep='/'))
      # some plots over dat
    })

  })
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probem arises from trying to dynamically create the choices for the file selection inside the `ui` part of your app. The way you should do this is to create the dynamic part of the `ui` (Your file selection) in your `server` part using `uiOutput` and `renderUI`

The following code seems to do what you describe you want:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(""),
  fluidRow(
    # select input for selecting a folder
    column(2, absolutePanel(fixed = TRUE, width = '180px',
                            selectInput("pick_folder", label = '', selected='choose_a_folder',
                                        choices = setNames(as.list(c('choose_a_folder', basename(setdiff(list.dirs(recursive = FALSE),'.')))), 
                                                           c('choose_a_folder', basename(setdiff(list.dirs(recursive = FALSE),'.'))))))),
    # select input for selecting a file absolutePanel then conditionalPanel
    column(2, absolutePanel(fixed = TRUE, width = '180px', 
                            conditionalPanel(condition="input.pick_folder==choose_a_folder",
                                             # Insert a dynamic bit of UI
                                             uiOutput("fileselection") 
                                             )
                            )
           )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    #plot
    plotOutput('my_plot')

  )))

# server
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$my_plot <- renderPlot({
    dat <- read.table(file=paste(input$pick_folder, input$pick_file, sep='/'))
    # some plots over dat
  })

  output$fileselection <- renderUI({  #Define the dynamic UI
    selectInput('pick_file', label = '', selected = 'choose_a_file',
                choices = setNames(as.list(c('choose_a_file', basename(setdiff(list.files(path=input$pick_folder ,recursive = FALSE),'.')))), 
                                   c('choose a file', basename(setdiff(list.files(path=input$pick_folder ,recursive = FALSE),'.'))
                                   )
                )
    )
  })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems I need to try and move most of my code to the server, it's the second time in the past week that this was the solution to my question.

Comment: The server is where all the thinking happens, so if your code is doing any thinking, it should probably be in the server. the UI is all about looks (so superficial, ugh!).